# Stream API, classes and casts

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-stream

I have these two methods:

```
Set<Class<?>> findAllClassesUsingClassLoader(String packageName)

void addNotRetryableExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... exceptionTypes)
```

This code does not compile even though it would run without any problem:

```
 findAllClassesUsingClassLoader("my.project.exception").stream()
     .filter(RuntimeException.class::isAssignableFrom)
     .map(x -> x.asSubclass(RuntimeException.class)) // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#14-of ? extends RuntimeException> to Class<RuntimeException>
     .forEach(recoverer::addNotRetryableExceptions);
```

How do I solve this properly?

Comment: Probably `Recoverer:: addNotRetryableExceptions`.

Comment: Btw. adding items into a different collection using `forEach` is not a way how the Stream API should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried several JDK versions from Java 8 to 17 and could not reproduce the error with `javac`, so this seems to be an Eclipse compiler problem.

You can work-around it by using

```java
.<Class<? extends RuntimeException>>map(x -> x.asSubclass(RuntimeException.class))
```

but I also see no reason for a compiler to infer `Class<RuntimeException>` here, so I think, `javac` is right and Eclipse’s compiler has a bug.